# How can I compute a repeated measurement ANOVA with a mixed model?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures

It is my task to program a mixed model. The data is from 20 experimental subjects, who were measured under 2 factors. Factor A has 7 levels, factor B has 3 levels. So, that for every subject I got 21 data points. The data points for one subject are repeated. I analysed the data with repeated measurement ANOVA just to know the influence of factor A and B.

Now I want to do my task. But I don't know what the model looks like. Because I have a random factor and two fixed effects. I wanted to compute the model about the variance components.

- Do I have to use the formula for a three-way ANOVA with mixed effects?
- How would I compute it in a regression model?
- Does my model look OK?

$Y = Z * \beta + X * b$ 
$Y$ ... data points 
$Z$ ... design matrix for random effects (20 x 20) 
$X$ ... design matrix for fixed effects (20 x 21)

**EDIT:** Yes, I have 21 data points. I used ANOVA with complete repeated measurement (also known as ANOVA with one observation per cell).

Comment: Do you really have 21 data points in total / s?  It's common in a repeated measures design to get multiple measures of each datapoint for each subject.  In an ANOVA those are aggregate out but in a mixed model you're best off keeping each individual data point.